# Exclude x window using matplotlib fill_between

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to exclude a x window range in plot using fill_between. Excluding a one sided range doing

```
x=np.linspace(1,100)    
plt.fill_between(x, -1, 1, alpha = 0.1, linewidth=0, facecolor='green', hatch='/////////', where= x<20)
```

will work and produce:

[image]

However if I just want to exclude a range x in [40, 60] using

```
plt.fill_between(x, -1, 1, alpha = 0.1, linewidth=0, facecolor='green', hatch='/////////', where= x<20 and x>60)
```

will not work with the error

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

However, using any() or all() does not lead to the desired result. What is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: First, you need `OR` instead of `AND`. Second, you need the array operator form (and brackets): `where= (x<20) | (x>60)`

Comment: or `np.logical_or(x<20, x>60)`